# can't access admin, composer related because of double declare of ComposerAutoloaderInit

Tags: php, composer-php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have Prestashop 1.7.3.3 installed, and I'm having problem logging in to the admin panel (back office), the front office works just fine.

when I try to view the back office on my browser I get:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit637ded6dc8ff9e657131d3b1c456aaa1, because the name is already in use in /Users/ufk/projects/luckylee/prestashop/prestashop-suite/PrestaShop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 5
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  369416  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0619  1647376 require_once( '/Users/ufk/projects/luckylee/prestashop/prestashop-suite/PrestaShop/app/bootstrap.php.cache' )   .../index.php:64
3   0.0619  1647616 require_once( '/Users/ufk/projects/luckylee/prestashop/prestashop-suite/PrestaShop/app/autoload.php' )  .../bootstrap.php.cache:5
4   0.0619  1647856 require_once( '/Users/ufk/projects/luckylee/prestashop/prestashop-suite/PrestaShop/vendor/autoload.php' )   .../autoload.php:34
```

any way to resolve this issue? for some reason reinstalling prestashop did not resolve it as well.

I use php 7.1.18. phpinfo output at https://paste.pound-python.org/show/TtVMy2EB96ETckEpmjUh/

the OS is macOS high sierra 10.13.4
installed php with home-brew.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had some sort of problem with my MacOS,
I formatted the drive and reinstalled the OS and reinstalled homebrew and the problem resolved. don't know the origin of the problem yet